# String aggregation using STUFF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-aggregation

Let's say I have table `#DOC` like this:

| polNum | boxNo | batchNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | null | qwe1234 |
| 111111 | ff/55 | rto1235 |
| 111111 | ee/59 | yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ww/55 | rto1235 |
| 222222 | dd/58 | jkl1234 |
| 222222 | null | fgh1234 |
| 333333 | null | asz1235 |
| 444444 | ff/55 | edc1234 |
| 444444 | tt/58 | qaz1234 |

This table doesn't have any primary key. We can assume that `polNum` and `boxNo` pair are unique.

I need have collection from `batchNum` and `boxNo` become like this:

| polNum | boxNo | batchNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | null |  |
| 111111 | ff/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ee/59 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ww/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 222222 | dd/58 | jkl1234,fgh1234 |
| 222222 | null |  |
| 333333 | null | asz1235 |
| 444444 | ff/55 | edc1234,qaz1234 |
| 444444 | tt/58 | edc1234,qaz1234 |

Need to manipulate `batchNum` row with comma separated based `polNum` and not empty `boxNo` and put same row. But if any condition `boxNo` is empty or null `batchNum` will put same `polNum` row.

I was tried using stuff approach, result still goes wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT polNum, boxNo ,
    STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ','+batchNum
        FROM #DOC a
        WHERE a.polNum=d.polNum or a.boxNo = d.boxNo
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') batchNum
FROM #DOC d
```

| polNum | boxNo | batchNum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | null | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ff/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ee/59 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 111111 | ww/55 | qwe1234,rto1235,yhn1238 |
| 222222 | dd/58 | jkl1234,fgh1234 |
| 222222 | null | jkl1234,fgh1234 |
| 333333 | null | asz1235 |
| 444444 | ff/55 | edc1234 |
| 444444 | tt/58 | qaz1234 |

`batchNum` is not always be null, depends on value of `boxNo` and `polNum`. Null row have values and some not. depend on `BoxNo` value itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what logic you are trying to achieve with regards to `null` rows, but it seems the logic might be:

- Same string aggregation on all rows per `polNum`
- If `boxNo` is `null` *and* there are other rows with the same `polNum` then replace the string aggregation with `null`

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Doc
    (polNum int, boxNo varchar(5), batchNum varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO #Doc
    (polNum, boxNo, batchNum)
VALUES
    (111111,    null,   'qwe1234'),
    (111111, 'ff/55', 'rto1235'),
    (111111, 'ee/59', 'yhn1238'),
    (111111, 'ww/55', 'rto1235'),
    (222222, 'dd/58', 'jkl1234'),
    (222222, NULL, 'fgh1234'),
    (333333, NULL, 'asz1235'),
    (444444, 'ff/55', 'edc1234'),
    (444444, 'tt/58', 'qaz1234')
;


SELECT polNum, boxNo ,
    CASE WHEN boxNo IS NOT NULL OR
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY polNum) = 1
    THEN
      STUFF((
        SELECT DISTINCT ','+batchNum
        FROM #DOC a
        WHERE a.polNum=d.polNum
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,LEN(','),'')
    END batchNum
FROM #DOC d
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2829d1d3f965e3f04ba0c967b4352e3f)